# I have some problems with LINQ expression, OrderBy(), Skip(), Take() works incorrect

Tags: linq, sql-order-by, skip, take

I have LINQ expression like

```
var a = ctx.EntitySet
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Property)
        .Skip(pageIndex * size) 
        .Take(size);
```

OrderBy() should call before Skip() and Take(), but sorting happens at the end. Can I solve this problem?

Sorry, many people didn't understand my question. Query runs without any errors, but I want

```
//It is I want
1) Sorting ALL data
2) Use Skip() and Take()
```

What I have in result if I do like at my example:
1) Skip()
2) Take()
3) Sorting only taked elements!

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Since the query looks fine, you might pass along the generated sql query since as-written it appears fine.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Comment: the code example worked for me, it ordered the set first, then skipped the amount, and then took the correct amount.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know why , but somehow it works for me , hope it helps you

```
var a1 = from p in ctx.EntitySet
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Property)
        select p;

var a2 = from p in a1
        .Skip(pageIndex * size) 
        .Take(size)
        select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

if you go for below solution it will first get the records and than does sorting on that records which may lead you to wrong result.

```
var a = ctx.EntitySet
        .Skip(pageIndex * size) 
        .Take(size);

a = a.OrderByDescending(t => t.Property);
```

or

Following way you first doing sorting and than getting records after that, so by this way you can get the result you want , this is proper way to do

```
   var a = ctx.EntitySet
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Property)
    .Skip(pageIndex * size) 
    .Take(size);
```

But it always depends on your requirement what you want....

Answer (score 0):

command orders in this sample is not Important. it will sort your data first and after that your data will be collected.